# OpenVPN Simple Remote Access

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I've now spent 2 days searching for any clue to create a proper OpenVPN configuration that meet my requirements. Now I hope that somebody of you understands this hell of possibilities.

#### Requirements

My goal is to allow VPN Clients to send requests to specific remote subnet: 192.168.1.0

But all other packets which aren't targeted to this subnet should be sent over to the local gateway or local subnet.

#### My first try

I've solved the second requirement (it's pretty easy you just have to make only one route push). But the remote Gateway (10.8.0.1) doesn't answer the requests for e.g. 192.168.1.90. But what it does is answering requests to 192.168.1.99 which is the local ip of my server.

Server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway"
```

Client config

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote quickme.at 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-128-CBC
verb 3
<ca>
```

#### My second try

Now I've discovered that there is tap too. Which establishes a bridge between two networks. So I switched to tap. But when I ping 192.168.1.90, 192.168.1.128 (my remote ip I got bridged to) answers destination host unreachable.

Server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp

dev tap
dev-node tap-bridge

server-bridge 192.168.1.99 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.128 192.168.1.254

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem

push "route-gateway 192.168.1.90"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Client config:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote b.bos.at 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-128-CBC
verb 3
<ca>
```

I'm happy with every solution that works ;)

Comment: Your first config doesn't look too bad, but the subnet in the pushed route is wrong, is that intentional?

Comment: No, it was a mistake of mine. But sadly that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I've edited my question because I've noticed a second thing

Comment: I cannot imagine that you haven't found a single clue about proper configuration. Could you link your ressources?

Comment: TUN [layer 3] is for connecting endpoints [PC, etc.] to the VPN, whereas TAP [layer 2] is to connect a router to the VPN; TAP acts like a transparent hardware switch, bridging two or more subnets so endpoints downstream of the two routers can access each other transparently. If the latter isn't what's being done, TUN should be used. General FYI: AES128 is uncrackable - TLS ciphers are recommended, and when using TLS GCM ciphers, AES256 has phenomenal throughout, but CBC does not _(the SSL cipher is specified as a fallback and throughout will take a massive drop if AES-256-CBC ends up used)_

Comment: For the tun case: `doesn't answer the requests for e.g. 192.168.1.90` pushing a route merely cause the clients to send corresponding traffics to the server; whether those traffics can reach their destination still depends on whether IP forwarding is enabled (e.g. sysctl on Linux) and allowed (in its firewall, if any). Besides, the destinations / LAN hosts will need to have route configured on them that leads their replies for the VPN client(s) back to the VPN server, *if* you haven't configured the server to masquerade the clients IP. None of these is configuration in OpenVPN btw.

Comment: @JW0914 thanks. I've updated the ciphers. And if I understood you right I should use TUN

Comment: @TomYan Yeah that makes sense. But I've enabled IP-Forwarding (Windows Registry). When a destination gets a packet from my VPN Server's IP, doesn't it send the answer back to my VPN Server. I always thought that when I use TUN all destinations don't know that there is even a VPN

Comment: `all destinations don't know that there is even a VPN` Only if you have source NAT (a.k.a. IP masquerade) set up for the VPN subnet/clients, in which case the traffics will appear to be originated from the VPN server, and therefore no extra route is needed on the LAN hosts. (I have no actual experience in setting up source NAT in Windows, but you probably want to take a look into [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netnat/new-netnat).)

Comment: @BierDav The SSL cipher in the config(s) would be the same format as before, just `128` instead of `256`: `AES-128-CBC` _(I've edited the configs to avoid any comments that the format isn't correct)_. If one of the VPN clients isn't a hardware/software router, or a server acting as a smart switch to route LAN side traffic independently of a hardware/software router, TUN would be recommended. There are more complex explanations on OpenVPN's site and their forum, but the simplest way to understand it is if a VPN client is an endpoint, use TUN, but if the client is a router, use TAP.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But why can't I than ping other destinations in my remote lan even though I've enabled IP Forwarding (without I'm not even able to ping the VPN Server's remote IP: 192.168.1.99)

Comment: @BierDav Your question lacks the info required to troubleshoot OpenVPN traffic: change the protocol to `tcp`, change server verbosity to `4`, client to `5`, restart the server, then reconnect the clients and attempt to access an IP. Review the system log of the machine the OpenVPN server is running on _(assumes firewall rules have been configured to allow the traffic between the VPN server's firewall zone/network interface and the LAN network/interface on the router/machine server is running on)_, the VPN server log, and the client log. Please post the logs if unable to determine the issue.

Comment: _(Cont'd)_ @BierDav When troubleshooting OpenVPN, TCP must be used, then switched back to UDP when done troubleshooting. There are only two use cases for using TCP in OpenVPN, troubleshooting or if receiving high packet loss with UDP, as TCP cannot efficiently encapsulate itself _(OpenVPN wraps its TCP packets within UDP packets, which is why higher throughput is gained when tuning the server config's MTU value to ~`48000` - the tunnel's MTU should not be mistaken for the ethernet adapter's MTU, which has nothing to do with the tunnel's MTU (adapter MTU is usually 1500 or slightly less))_

Comment: Thanks. But the logs really say nothing interesting. There are no errors that on the server nore the client that the server doesn't know where to send the packets

Comment: Because none of the above is related to the problem you've bumped into. (Some of the statements aren't exactly facts either.) Clearly the VPN itself works fine. It's just the missing return route / IP masquerade that has been preventing LAN host replies from getting to the server (instead they are routed to their default gateway, i.e. the LAN router, and in turn its default gateway, and ultimately get ignored or so by the ISP the server is connected to).

Comment: So my Dream Machine (Router on the server side) gets the packets? But why can't my server just send the packets under it's ip? If it did that the packets must have gotten back to my server

Comment: It can. You just have to configure Windows to masquerade for the VPN subnet. I told you to take a look into the NetNat PS cmdlet.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to understand that ;). I've really know idea what weird things the Windows adapters do and why NetNat should help to fix that. Nore I know what IP masquerade is. But I'm sure that I will find the necessary things.

Comment: In case you are still confused about IP masquerade: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#One-to-many_NAT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the ip packets get sent with the virtual subnet ip of the remote clients e.g. 10.8.0.2

The receiver send the response to it's default gateway because the virtual subnet is obviously not in it's subnet.

At the end the answer gets thrown away by the default gateway because it doesn't know what to do with this packet.

For this there are two solutions:

#### First solution

Add a static route to all you hosts you want to access in your remote lan. So that answer packets get sent to another gateway: the vpn server.

Static routes are defined in Windows with route like this:
`route add 10.8.0.0/24 192.168.1.99` This should probably work, I've not tested it.

#### Second solution

Add a static route on your router (default gateway) that tells it to send the packets over to the vpn server (192.168.1.99)

#### Third solution

Masquerade all the traffic from the vpn clients. That means changing the source ip to your vpn server's ip. For more information look there: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting

If you have a Windows on the server side you may need NetNat to configure this.

#### Comparison

All of the solutions have a drawback.

For the first solution the problem is that you have to configure a autostart so that the routes get added after a restart too.

The third solution needs the gateway to forward all answer packets which adds latency and overhead.

The second solution on the otherhad hides the source ip. That's often bad for debuging where ip packets are really coming from.

#### Notes

At the end I went with the second solution, because it was the best compromise between maintainability and debuggability.

I've also forgotten to add a dns server in my configuration: https://serverfault.com/questions/318563/how-to-push-my-own-dns-server-to-openvpn

If I'm wrong with anything of this. Feel free to comment or edit. I'm only combining my knowledge with my recent researches.

Comment: Regarding the "first solution", ideally speaking the route should be configured on every LAN hosts. Unfortunately most consumer-grade routers do not have way for you to add extra route for its DHCP server to announce. On the other hand, the linked page in "second solution" mentions nothing about how IP masquerade can be set up on Windows, which is the server's OS in your case. (But yeah, basically you just need to set up an equivalence of the iptables MASQUERADE rule, which I *believe* can be done with the NetNat cmdlet.)

Comment: I've updated my answer. But as said I don't know any commands for Windows